# Error: Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to set up a timer on the server for a game I'm creating but I keep getting the 'Call to a member function stop() on a non-object' error.

To start the time, I make the following ajax call

```
$.post('game.php', {
    action: 'start'
}, function(res) {
},'json');
```

When the game is over I try to stop the timer by making the following ajax call

```
$.post('game.php', {
    action: 'stop'
}, function(res) {
},'json');
```

game.php code is

```
$action = $_POST['action'];

switch($action) {
case 'start':
    $gameTime = new timer();
    $gameTime->start();
    break;
case 'stop':
    $gameTime->stop();
    break;
}

class Timer {

   var $classname = "Timer";
   var $start     = 0;
   var $stop      = 0;
   var $elapsed   = 0;

   # Constructor
   function Timer( $start = true ) {
      if ( $start )
         $this->start();
   }

   # Start counting time
   function start() {
      $this->start = $this->_gettime();
   }

   # Stop counting time
   function stop() {
      $this->stop    = $this->_gettime();
      $this->elapsed = $this->_compute();
   }

   # Get Elapsed Time
   function elapsed() {
      if ( !$elapsed )
         $this->stop();

      return $this->elapsed;
   }

   # Get Elapsed Time
   function reset() {
      $this->start   = 0;
      $this->stop    = 0;
      $this->elapsed = 0;
   }

   #### PRIVATE METHODS ####

   # Get Current Time
   function _gettime() {
      $mtime = microtime();
      $mtime = explode( " ", $mtime );
      return $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
   }

   # Compute elapsed time
   function _compute() {
      return $this->stop - $this->start;
   }
}
```

When I make the call to stop the timer, I get the error.
I've tried to find what's wrong and am wondering if it is because I'm making ajax calls?

Does anyone know a way to get this working?

Comment: Do you know that PHP script **terminates** when it's completed? You will not be able to turn on/off your timer for some time as once your script ended, your timer object is gone

Answer (score 1):

this

```
switch($action) {
case 'start':
    $gameTime = new timer();
    $gameTime->start();
    break;
case 'stop':
                   <-----there should be  $gameTime = new timer();
    $gameTime->stop();
    break;
}
```

should be

```
 switch($action) {
    case 'start':
        $gameTime = new timer();
        $gameTime->start();
        break;
    case 'stop':
     $gameTime = new timer();
        $gameTime->stop();
        break;

}
```

or try

```
  $gameTime = new timer();
      switch($action) {
    case 'start':

        $gameTime->start();
        break;
    case 'stop':

        $gameTime->stop();
        break;

}
```

Comment: Won't I get a new timer each time I use $gameTime = new timer();? Resulting in stop time = 0? I'm thinking I should maybe grab the time when the game starts, write it to a database, then grab the time when the game ends and compare with what is on the database. Does that sound the best way to you guys?

Answer (score 0):

In your stop case, you have to initialize the timer like you did in the start case.